# Why cant I use more than 1 deleteRow() for many tables in SQL?I found that only the 1st rs's row is deleted, the others arent

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jdbc

```
String SQL="Select * from APARTMENT_ADDONS";

String SQL2="Select * from APARTMENT_ID";

String SQL3="Select * from APARTMENT_AVAILABLE";

String SQL4="Select * from APARTMENT_COST";

stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

stmt2 = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

stmt3 = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

stmt4 = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

rs=stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

rs2=stmt2.executeQuery(SQL2);

rs3=stmt3.executeQuery(SQL3);

rs4=stmt4.executeQuery(SQL4);

rs.deleteRow();

rs2.deleteRow();

rs3.deleteRow();

rs4.deleteRow();
```

Comment: Do you get any errors ?

Comment: You would need to do at least one `ResultSet.next()` before you can even call `deleteRow()`. You should be getting exceptions of that nature,

Comment: No, I dont receive any exceptions - but i do get an Invalid Cursor error that pops up. But only data from the first result set is deleted

Answer (score 0):

`ResultSet.deleteRow()` only deletes the current row of the resultset.  If you want to delete more than one, run something like:-

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE Whatever = 'Something'";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

(Ideally using PreparedStatements of course).

Comment: If you look closely, they are 4 different record sets!

Comment: Yes, one for each table.

Comment: Thanks Steve - Yeah I used PreparedStatement instead and it works and updates the 4 resultsets.